# Правильная последовательность скобок не работает с нечётными числами

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть две функции (**even_generate_brackets** и **odd_generate_brackets**), в 
первой функции у меня обрабатываются чётные числа и выводится правильная последовательность скобок соответственно. Что мне сделать со второй функцией, чтобы работала с нечётными цифрами?

```py
def even_generate_brackets(n, count, stack, result):

    # Вывод не чётного числа скобок
    if count == n // 2 and len(stack) == 0:
        print(result)
        return

    # Обработка правой части со скобками
    if count < n // 2:
        even_generate_brackets(n, count + 1, stack + '(', result + '(')

    # Очистка "стека" и добавление противоположной скобки       
    if len(stack) > 0:
        if stack[-1] == '(':
            even_generate_brackets(n, count, stack[:-1], result + ')')

def odd_generate_brackets(n, count, stack, result):

    # Вывод нечётного числа скобок
    if count == n // 2 and len(stack) == 0:
      print(result)
      return

    # Обработка правой части со скобками 
    if count < n // 2:
        odd_generate_brackets(n, count + 1, stack + '(', result + '(')

    # Очистка "стека" и добавление противоположной скобки
    if len(stack) > 0:
      if stack[-1] == '(':
        odd_generate_brackets(n, count, stack[:-1], result + ')')


n = int(input())

#  Проверка на чётность и нечётность вводного числа
if (n % 2 == 0) & (n <= 12) & (n > 0):
  n = n + 2
  even_generate_brackets(n, 0, "", "")
elif (n % 2 != 0) & (n <= 12) & (n > 0): 
  odd_generate_brackets(n, 0, "", "")
```

Вывод even_generate_brackets при значении n = 2:

```
(())
()()
```

Вывод odd_generate_brackets при значении n = 3:

```
()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо вы имеете в виду четное и нечетное количество пар, но это как раз и не важно. Вот пример кода

```
def printBrackets(str, n):
    if (n > 0):
        shuffle(str, 0, n, 0, 0)
    return;


def shuffle(str, pos, n, open, close):
    if (close == n):
        for i in str:
            print(i, end="")
        print()
        return
    else:
        if (open > close):
            str[pos] = ')'
            shuffle(str, pos + 1, n, open, close + 1)
        if (open < n):
            str[pos] = '('
            shuffle(str, pos + 1, n, open + 1, close)


n = int(input("n= "))

str = [""] * 2 * n
printBrackets(str, n)
```

Comment: Воу, спасибо огроменное, долго голову ломал)